How does <$ = (fmap . const) in Functor even work in Haskell?
I know that the dot (.) operator takes two functions which both take an argument respectively, and the third argument for the second argument.
Its type is (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c.
For example, take 1 . drop 2 $ [1,2,3,4,5].
But how can (fmap . const) work?
The fmap function needs two arguments, and the const function takes two arguments and then return the first argument.
So logically, the fmap should take the output which is the first argument taken by the const function.
The types of two functions:
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
const :: a -> b -> a

The fmap in (fmap . const) 2 (Just 4) should get the output 2 returned by the const function, so it'd not work, but actually it does work.
What happened?

"The fmap in (fmap . const) 2 should get the output 2 returned by the const function" -- no, the fmap in (fmap . const) 2 gets the output \_ -> 2 returned by the const function. const x _ = x is essentially the same equation as const x = \_ -> x.

Just unify the types:
fmap         :: Functor f =>      (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
const        ::              b -> (a -> b)
fmap . const :: Functor f => b             -> (f a -> f b)

So fmap . const takes x :: b and produces fmap (const x) :: f a -> f b.
In your example,
  (fmap . const) 2 (Just 4)
= ((fmap . const) 2) (Just 4)
= fmap (const 2) (Just 4)
= Just (const 2 4)
= Just 4


That's abstruse for how it actually works, please take a look at the comments below the answer by @willeM_Van Onsem. So (a -> b) could also be (a -> (x -> z)), or for the case of fmap in the dot operator, it could also be Functor f => ((a -> b) -> (f a -> f b))? How could an algebraic type be a type of value or also could be a type of function?

Yes, type variables like b stand for any (monomorphic) type, not just algebraic data types. This is why they're so powerful: you can compose any two functions as long as their domain and codomain match.

Functions are also values; you could say that's the entire point of functional programming.

Furthermore, to be more complete to understand the whole picture, based on the polymorphic nature of type variables, and monomorphic inference of the type of an expression(also function application, application of a function composition), the composition fmap . const, its type is like (.) :: Functor f => ((f b -> a) -> (f b -> f a)) -> (((a -> (f b -> a)) -> ((((a -> f b) -> f a))))),

where an application (fmap . const) 2 (Just 4) looks like that the dot operator takes four arugments, but actually it's not, its result is a function, that takes care of the forth argument... So the expression for the application like fmap . const $ 2 (Just 4) is invalid, but requires to be (fmap . const) 2 (Just 4), or furthermore without parenthesis simiplication that's allowed the compiler, ((fmap . const) 2) (Just 4). Too much I guess, that's the hard part to be functional. @Naim Favier, do I understand it the right way?..

Not quite: the instance of (.) we're using here has type ((a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)) -> (b -> (a -> b)) -> (b -> (f a -> f b)).

It was edited wrong even for my wrong understanding, it was gonna be (.) :: Functor f => ((f b -> a) -> (f b -> f a)) -> ((a -> (f b -> a)) -> (f b -> f a),
not (.) :: Functor f => ((f b -> a) -> (f b -> f a)) -> (((a -> (f b -> a)) -> ((((a -> f b) -> f a))))). I also tried your type signature by
`(.) :: Functor f => ((a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)) -> (b -> (a -> b)) -> (b -> (f a -> f b))
(.) f g = \x -> f (g x) ` in Haskell, it indeed works


The fmap function needs two arguments, and the const function takes two arguments and then return the first argument.

No, every function takes one parameter, and sometimes produces a function as result. fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b), takes one function, of type a -> b, and then produces a function that maps an f a to an f b.
Now, the same trick is necessary when we work with const :: c -> d -> c, this is short for const :: c -> (d -> c), so again, a function that takes a value, and then produces a function that will map any value to the given value.
So then what is fmap . const? It is short for \x -> fmap (const x). It thus asks for a value x, and then produces an fmap (const x), this thus means that fmap will map any value to x. This thus means that if we work for example with x = 42, and a list [1,4,2,5], we get fmap (const 42) [1,4,2,5], and this thus means that we map any item of the list to 42, so [42, 42, 42, 42].

"So then what is fmap . const? It is short for \x -> fmap (const x)", this is not strictly Inferential from its type signature (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c in my view. I still need to look into the implementation of the dot operator like other answers explained.

This is why it's confusing, I can't understand by directly looking at the type signature of the dot operator. I was told that type signature would tell how a function/operator works, but obviously it's not a case at lease for some situations like this, even with the perspective of currying. That's the problem. I was confused by its type signature. Now when looking into how the dot operator is implemented, it's very clear

Or could it mean that (a -> b) would also probably indicate, that it takes an argument and probably returns another function, like (a -> (x -> z))., in the fmap taken by the dot as the first argument, it would be (a -> b) equal to Functor f => ((a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)) then what's the point of looking for type signatures, if an algebraic type could mean not only a type of value, but also a type of function..

Yes, b can be any type, it's not constrained in any way. That includes function types because why would function types be different here?

@Akari technically the type tells you everything you need to know, as there is only one (total) function with that type signature by parametricity/free theorems. It's a matter of experience, I suppose.

@Akari A key thing you will have to get used to to be comfortable in Haskell is to stop thinking of functions as separate from values. "Function" describes a subcategory of values, not a wholly different thing. Functions are values. In exactly the same way that "list" describes a subcategory of values, not something else. So when you see something that applies to any type of value (such as a type variable like b), that includes the possibility (but not necessity) of it applying to functions. So in fact the type did tell you it could be a function; that's what type variables mean!

Function composition, ., is defined as:
f . g = \x -> f (g x)

By replacing . with its definition in fmap . const you obtain the equivalent expression:
\x -> fmap (const x)

Similarly, if you replace fmap . const in the expression (fmap . const) 2 with its equivalent, \x -> fmap (const x), you obtain:
(\x -> fmap (const x)) 2

Finally, applying the argument 2 above:
fmap (const 2)

